# AngularFire UPDATE -> WHERE

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I not find something here. My question is how UPDATE a document returned in WHERE clausule in AngularFire:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

var path = this.db.collection('users').doc('type').collection('customer')
.ref.where('name', '==', 'roger');
```

**how UPDATE this user ?**

```
var query = path.set/update..?
```

not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand how the previous answer got accepted because the behaviour is wrong and ends in an infinite loop (`snapshotChanges()` triggers `update()`, which again, triggers `snapshotChanges()` as it has subscribed to it.) Also, this angularfire synatx is outdated so I will point out a different approach.

To achieve the behaviour OP is looking for, the best practice is to store the document ID in the document itself. When creating an item, `add()` returns a `DocumentReference`, which includes the ID of the just inserted item.

An example implementation would be:

```
 create(user) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db
        .collection('users')
        .doc('type')
        .collection('customer')
        .add(user)
        .then(res => {
          this.updateUserId(res.id);  
        }, err => reject(err));
    });
  }

  updateUserId(id: string) {
    return this.db
      .collection('users')
      .doc('type')
      .collection('customer')
      .doc(id)
      .set({ id: id }, { merge: true });
  }
```

In this case, the user would be created and immediately afterwards, the `id` field of the `user` object would be updated (as the Firestore document ID is only available after insertion). Now the user can easily be updated via the user's document ID.

Comment: Hi, dude. I make something little changes in code answer marked and working for me. Sorry cant share code now, I haven't project with me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, query will give you a list you need to get the id and perform update.

```
const query = this.db.collection('users').doc('type').collection('customer', ref => ref.where('name', '==', 'roger'));

query.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
   changes.map(a => {
    const id = a.payload.doc.id; 
    this.db.collection('users').doc('type').collection('customer').doc(id).update({})
  })
}).subscribe();
```

Comment: Hey dude. Thanks but I'm receiving this ERROR: [ts] property 'snapshotChanges' does not exist on type 'Query' –